# Apache Ignite: IgniteCheckedException: Unknown pair

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

I am trying to implement Ignite 3rd party persistence with SQL Server. I used the Web Console to generate the java model and I am able to execute the generated utility and configuration files without any issue (LoadCaches or ServerNodeCodeStartup, with config from ServerConfigurationFactory) -- the cache load call executes without any problem.

```
    public TestPersistentStore() throws Exception {
    try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(ServerConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration())) {

        // Auto-close cache at the end of the example.
        try (IgniteCache<Integer, Customer> cache = ignite.cache("CustomerCache")) {
            // Make initial cache loading from persistent store. This is a
            // distributed operation and will call CacheStore.loadCache(...)
            // method on all nodes in topology.
            loadCache(cache);

            // Start transaction and execute several cache operations with
            // read/write-through to persistent store.
            executeTransaction(cache);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Distributed cache could be removed from cluster only by #destroyCache() call.
            ignite.destroyCache("CustomerCache");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Content of executeTransaction:

```
    private static void executeTransaction(IgniteCache<Integer, Customer> cache) {
    int id = 1;

    try (Transaction tx = Ignition.ignite("acmecorp").transactions().txStart()) {
        Customer val = cache.get(id);

        System.out.println("Read value: " + val);

        val = cache.getAndPut(id, new Customer(id, "Isaac", "Newton", "Ixelles"));

        System.out.println("Overwrote old value: " + val);

        val = cache.get(id);

        System.out.println("Read value: " + val);

        tx.commit();
    }

    System.out.println("Read value after commit: " + cache.get(id));
}
```

(many of these lines of code were copied from CacheJdbcStoreExample)

Result of execution:

```
[22:53:35] Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=3.5GB]
>>> Loaded 10 keys with backups in 450ms.
Read value: Customer [firstName=Isaac, lastName=Newton, address=Ixelles]
Overwrote old value: Customer [firstName=Isaac, lastName=Newton, address=Ixelles]
Read value: Customer [firstName=Isaac, lastName=Newton, address=Ixelles]
Read value after commit: Customer [firstName=Isaac, lastName=Newton, address=Ixelles]
Read value skipping store (expecting null): null
Read value with store lookup (expecting NOT null): Customer [firstName=Isaac, lastName=Newton, address=Ixelles]
Read value skipping store (expecting NOT null): Customer [firstName=Isaac, lastName=Newton, address=Ixelles]
[22:53:36] Ignite node stopped OK [name=acmecorp, uptime=00:00:00:638]
```

So this works for the **Customer** table/cache. I want to use the same code but use another table/cache (**Item**), as follows:

TestPersistentStore2

```
public TestPersistentStore2() throws Exception {
    try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(ServerConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration())) {

        // Auto-close cache at the end of the example.
        try (IgniteCache<Integer, Item> cache = ignite.cache("ItemCache")) {
            // Make initial cache loading from persistent store. This is a
            // distributed operation and will call CacheStore.loadCache(...)
            // method on all nodes in topology.
            loadCache(cache);

            // Start transaction and execute several cache operations with
            // read/write-through to persistent store.
            executeTransaction(cache);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("sumthin happened");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Distributed cache could be removed from cluster only by #destroyCache() call.
            ignite.destroyCache("ItemCache");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

TestPersistentStore2#executeTransaction

```
private static void executeTransaction(IgniteCache<Integer, Item> cache) {
        int id = 1;

        try (Transaction tx = Ignition.ignite("acmecorp").transactions().txStart()) {
            Item val = cache.get(id);

            System.out.println("Read value: " + val);

            val = cache.getAndPut(id, new Item(id, "n", "b", "t", "m", "d"));

            System.out.println("Overwrote old value: " + val);

            val = cache.get(id);

            System.out.println("Read value: " + val);

            tx.commit();
        }

        System.out.println("Read value after commit: " + cache.get(id));

        // Clear entry from memory, but keep it in store.
        cache.clear(id);

        // Operations on this cache will not affect store.
        IgniteCache<Integer, Item> cacheSkipStore = cache.withSkipStore();

        System.out.println("Read value skipping store (expecting null): " + cacheSkipStore.get(id));

        System.out.println("Read value with store lookup (expecting NOT null): " + cache.get(id));

        // Expecting not null, since entry should be in memory since last call.
        System.out.println("Read value skipping store (expecting NOT null): " + cacheSkipStore.get(id));
    }
```

However I get the following exception in the cache.get(id) call of executeTransaction:

```
>>> Loaded 72 keys with backups in 648ms.
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=123254525]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1312)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.cacheException(IgniteCacheProxy.java:2630)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.get(IgniteCacheProxy.java:1188)
    at infoh415.project.test.TestPersistentStore2.executeTransaction(TestPersistentStore2.java:98)
    at infoh415.project.test.TestPersistentStore2.<init>(TestPersistentStore2.java:69)
    at infoh415.project.test.TestPersistentStore2.main(TestPersistentStore2.java:130)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=123254525]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7229)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:258)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:170)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:139)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get0(GridCacheAdapter.java:4499)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:4480)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.get(GridCacheAdapter.java:1324)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.get(IgniteCacheProxy.java:1181)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=123254525]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:392)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:342)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:686)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1755)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1714)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.deserializeValue(BinaryObjectImpl.java:797)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl.value(BinaryObjectImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinary(CacheObjectUtils.java:161)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectUtils.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectUtils.java:41)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheObjectContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(CacheObjectContext.java:125)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1734)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheContext.unwrapBinaryIfNeeded(GridCacheContext.java:1722)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.setResult(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:645)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.localGet(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:438)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.mapKeyToNode(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:324)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.map(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:212)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.init(GridPartitionedSingleGetFuture.java:204)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.getAsync0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1445)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$1600(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:129)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$16.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:513)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$16.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:511)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.asyncOp(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:806)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.getAsync(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:511)
    ... 7 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49513', transport: 'socket'
```

I double checked the differences between the CacheConfiguration for CustomerCache and for ItemCache, there is nothing unexpected (the only differnces are in the table and field names). I also compared the model classes, again they are similar.

Attaching here the config of **CustomerCache**

```
    /**
 * Create configuration for cache "CustomerCache".
 * 
 * @return Configured cache.
 * @throws Exception if failed to create cache configuration.
 **/
public static CacheConfiguration cacheCustomerCache() throws Exception {
    CacheConfiguration ccfg = new CacheConfiguration();

    ccfg.setName("CustomerCache");
    ccfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    ccfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);

    CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory cacheStoreFactory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory();

    cacheStoreFactory.setDataSourceFactory(new Factory<DataSource>() {
        /** {@inheritDoc} **/
        @Override public DataSource create() {
            return DataSources.INSTANCE_dsSQLServer_Acmecorp;
        };
    });

    cacheStoreFactory.setDialect(new SQLServerDialect());

    cacheStoreFactory.setTypes(jdbcTypeCustomer(ccfg.getName()));

    ccfg.setCacheStoreFactory(cacheStoreFactory);

    ccfg.setReadThrough(true);
    ccfg.setWriteThrough(true);

    ArrayList<QueryEntity> qryEntities = new ArrayList<>();

    QueryEntity qryEntity = new QueryEntity();

    qryEntity.setKeyType("java.lang.Integer");
    qryEntity.setValueType("infoh415.project.model.Customer");
    qryEntity.setKeyFieldName("customerId");

    HashSet<String> keyFields = new HashSet<>();

    keyFields.add("customerId");

    qryEntity.setKeyFields(keyFields);

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    fields.put("firstName", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("lastName", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("address", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("customerId", "java.lang.Integer");

    qryEntity.setFields(fields);

    HashMap<String, String> aliases = new HashMap<>();

    aliases.put("customerId", "customer_id");
    aliases.put("firstName", "first_name");
    aliases.put("lastName", "last_name");

    qryEntity.setAliases(aliases);
    qryEntities.add(qryEntity);

    ccfg.setQueryEntities(qryEntities);

    return ccfg;
}

/**
 * Create JDBC type for "jdbcTypeCustomer".
 * 
 * @param cacheName Cache name.
 * @return Configured JDBC type.
 **/
private static JdbcType jdbcTypeCustomer(String cacheName) {
    JdbcType type = new JdbcType();

    type.setCacheName(cacheName);
    type.setKeyType(Integer.class);
    type.setValueType("infoh415.project.model.Customer");
    type.setDatabaseSchema("dbo");
    type.setDatabaseTable("Customer");

    type.setKeyFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "customer_id", int.class, "customerId"));

    type.setValueFields(
        new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "first_name", String.class, "firstName"),
        new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "last_name", String.class, "lastName"),
        new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "address", String.class, "address")
    );

    return type;
}
```

vs. config of **ItemCache**

```
/**
 * Create configuration for cache "ItemCache".
 * 
 * @return Configured cache.
 * @throws Exception if failed to create cache configuration.
 **/
public static CacheConfiguration cacheItemCache() throws Exception {
    CacheConfiguration ccfg = new CacheConfiguration();

    ccfg.setName("ItemCache");
    ccfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    ccfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);

    CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory cacheStoreFactory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory();

    cacheStoreFactory.setDataSourceFactory(new Factory<DataSource>() {
        /** {@inheritDoc} **/
        @Override public DataSource create() {
            return DataSources.INSTANCE_dsSQLServer_Acmecorp;
        };
    });

    cacheStoreFactory.setDialect(new SQLServerDialect());

    cacheStoreFactory.setTypes(jdbcTypeItem(ccfg.getName()));

    ccfg.setCacheStoreFactory(cacheStoreFactory);

    ccfg.setReadThrough(true);
    ccfg.setWriteThrough(true);

    ArrayList<QueryEntity> qryEntities = new ArrayList<>();

    QueryEntity qryEntity = new QueryEntity();

    qryEntity.setKeyType("java.lang.Integer");
    qryEntity.setValueType("infoh415.project.model.Item");
    qryEntity.setKeyFieldName("itemId");

    HashSet<String> keyFields = new HashSet<>();

    keyFields.add("itemId");

    qryEntity.setKeyFields(keyFields);

    LinkedHashMap<String, String> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    fields.put("name", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("brand", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("type", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("manufacturer", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("description", "java.lang.String");
    fields.put("itemId", "java.lang.Integer");

    qryEntity.setFields(fields);

    HashMap<String, String> aliases = new HashMap<>();

    aliases.put("itemId", "item_id");

    qryEntity.setAliases(aliases);
    qryEntities.add(qryEntity);

    ccfg.setQueryEntities(qryEntities);

    return ccfg;
}

/**
 * Create JDBC type for "jdbcTypeItem".
 * 
 * @param cacheName Cache name.
 * @return Configured JDBC type.
 **/
private static JdbcType jdbcTypeItem(String cacheName) {
    JdbcType type = new JdbcType();

    type.setCacheName(cacheName);
    type.setKeyType(Integer.class);
    type.setValueType("infoh415.project.model.Item");
    type.setDatabaseSchema("dbo");
    type.setDatabaseTable("Item");

    type.setKeyFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "item_id", int.class, "itemId"));

    type.setValueFields(
        new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "name", String.class, "name"),
        new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "brand", String.class, "brand"),
        new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "type", String.class, "type"),
        new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "manufacturer", String.class, "manufacturer"),
        new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "description", String.class, "description")
    );

    return type;
}
```

Model class of **Customer**

```
package infoh415.project.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Customer definition.
 * 
 * This file was generated by Ignite Web Console (11/26/2017, 10:52)
 **/
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    /** */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    private int customerId;

    /** Value for firstName. */
    private String firstName;

    /** Value for lastName. */
    private String lastName;

    /** Value for address. */
    private String address;

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Customer(int customerId, String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    /**
     * Gets firstName
     * 
     * @return Value for firstName.
     **/
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets firstName
     * 
     * @param firstName New value for firstName.
     **/
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets lastName
     * 
     * @return Value for lastName.
     **/
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets lastName
     * 
     * @param lastName New value for lastName.
     **/
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Gets address
     * 
     * @return Value for address.
     **/
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * Sets address
     * 
     * @param address New value for address.
     **/
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} **/
    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;

        if (!(o instanceof Customer))
            return false;

        Customer that = (Customer)o;

        if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(that.firstName) : that.firstName != null)
            return false;


        if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(that.lastName) : that.lastName != null)
            return false;


        if (address != null ? !address.equals(that.address) : that.address != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} **/
    @Override public int hashCode() {
        int res = firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0;

        res = 31 * res + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);

        res = 31 * res + (address != null ? address.hashCode() : 0);

        return res;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} **/
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Customer [" + 
            "firstName=" + firstName + ", " + 
            "lastName=" + lastName + ", " + 
            "address=" + address +
        "]";
    }
}
```

Model class of **Item**

```
package infoh415.project.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Item definition.
 * 
 * This file was generated by Ignite Web Console (11/26/2017, 10:52)
 **/
public class Item implements Serializable {
    /** */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    private int itemId;

    /** Value for name. */
    private String name;

    /** Value for brand. */
    private String brand;

    /** Value for type. */
    private String type;

    /** Value for manufacturer. */
    private String manufacturer;

    /** Value for description. */
    private String description;

    public Item(String name, String brand, String type, String manufacturer, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.type = type;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Item(int itemId, String name, String brand, String type, String manufacturer, String description) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.name = name;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.type = type;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    /**
     * Gets name
     * 
     * @return Value for name.
     **/
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets name
     * 
     * @param name New value for name.
     **/
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Gets brand
     * 
     * @return Value for brand.
     **/
    public String getBrand() {
        return brand;
    }

    /**
     * Sets brand
     * 
     * @param brand New value for brand.
     **/
    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    /**
     * Gets type
     * 
     * @return Value for type.
     **/
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     * Sets type
     * 
     * @param type New value for type.
     **/
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * Gets manufacturer
     * 
     * @return Value for manufacturer.
     **/
    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    /**
     * Sets manufacturer
     * 
     * @param manufacturer New value for manufacturer.
     **/
    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    /**
     * Gets description
     * 
     * @return Value for description.
     **/
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Sets description
     * 
     * @param description New value for description.
     **/
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} **/
    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;

        if (!(o instanceof Item))
            return false;

        Item that = (Item)o;

        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null)
            return false;


        if (brand != null ? !brand.equals(that.brand) : that.brand != null)
            return false;


        if (type != null ? !type.equals(that.type) : that.type != null)
            return false;


        if (manufacturer != null ? !manufacturer.equals(that.manufacturer) : that.manufacturer != null)
            return false;


        if (description != null ? !description.equals(that.description) : that.description != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} **/
    @Override public int hashCode() {
        int res = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;

        res = 31 * res + (brand != null ? brand.hashCode() : 0);

        res = 31 * res + (type != null ? type.hashCode() : 0);

        res = 31 * res + (manufacturer != null ? manufacturer.hashCode() : 0);

        res = 31 * res + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);

        return res;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} **/
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Item [" + 
            "name=" + name + ", " + 
            "brand=" + brand + ", " + 
            "type=" + type + ", " + 
            "manufacturer=" + manufacturer + ", " + 
            "description=" + description +
        "]";
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain what the "class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Unknown pair [platformId=0, typeId=123254525]" error means and how to trace the cause of this issue - I already tried stepping through the Ignite code in debug mode, I know that in MarshallerContextImpl#getClassName the first line MappedName mappedName = cache.get(typeId); yields null for Item. But I do not understand why. Any help would be appreciated!! Thank you.

UPDATE:
Ignite version used: ignite-core 2.2.0

Update: content of loadCache:

```
private static void loadCache(IgniteCache<Integer, Item> cache) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Start loading cache from persistent store on all caching nodes.
        //      cache.loadCache(null, ENTRY_COUNT);
        cache.loadCache(null);

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println(">>> Loaded " + cache.size() + " keys with backups in " + (end - start) + "ms.");
    }
```

Table definition of the Item table:

```
create table Item
(
    item_id int not null
        primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    brand varchar(20) not null,
    type varchar(20) not null,
    manufacturer varchar(30) not null,
    description varchar(200)
)
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue, can you please share the exact method that is failing, instead of non-failing one? What Ignite version are you using?

Comment: I am using ignite-core 2.2.0. Updating the description above.

Comment: Added the loadCache method and the table definition of Item. i will check if i have any unexpected data in my table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce it when, in `loadCaches()`, I put something that isn't exactly the expected Item in the cache:

```
private void loadCache(IgniteCache<Integer, Item> cache, /* Ignite.binary() */ IgniteBinary binary) {
    // Note the absence of package name here:  
    BinaryObjectBuilder builder = binary.builder("Item");
    builder.setField("name", "a");
    builder.setField("brand", "B");
    builder.setField("type", "c");
    builder.setField("manufacturer", "D");
    builder.setField("description", "e");
    builder.setField("itemId", 1);

    cache.withKeepBinary().put(1, builder.build());
}
```

Please share your `loadCaches` method for scrutiny.

Comment: I cleared my Item table and reinserted everything and now the issue does not occur. I don't know why. But thanks for the tip-- it could have been some value in the table that was causing it to fail. Anyhow, thanks for the tip!